# EBS volume size?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm looking at setting up an ubuntu instance with EC2.

It's asking me about EBS and the size in GB I need.

How do I know how much size I would need? All I want to do is run a few websites using nginx and install and run mysql.

I'm not expecting a huge amount of traffic.

What factors do you need to consider when picking a volume size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much hard drive space to install MYSQL, PHP7 & nginx?](http://serverfault.com/questions/807978/how-much-hard-drive-space-to-install-mysql-php7-nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider following things.
1. What is the source code size for your websites.
2. Are you going to use the MySQL on system or AWS RDS instance?

Considering these 2 facts you can decide. For instance Assuming 4 websites each of which have source code of 150 Mb. And Also assuming MySQL installed on ec2. A 20 GB EBS Volume is enough considering that all backups are on S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks, how large would a MYSQL install be?

Comment: Installation of MySQL doesn't take more than 200 Mb of your disk space.